# Android OAuth2 AppAuth library example in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, appauth

I find difficulties in using AppAuth Library for android, I would appreciate anyone who can provide me a sample example in kotlin using AppAuth library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check this tutorial for appAuth in kotlin.

https://howtodoandroid.medium.com/appauth-android-velmm-com-d52a4980a668

Comment: I've already checked this article but the problem is the main part of the code is in java and I think there is a better way to do it in Kotlin

Comment: AuthStateManager